# pyinstaller ignores hiddenimports in a hook file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I cannot get pyinstaller working correctly with a hook file. According to the documentation the following set up should work, but it does not. Module is called *owl*.

hook-owl.py:

```
hiddenimports=['pyodbc']
```

Command line:

```
pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --onefile --name=owl --additional-hooks-dir=.  service.py
```

I can see that the hook file is read:

```
8704 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
9193 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-owl.py"...
9219 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
```

But the spec file does not contain hidden imports specified in the hook file.

I am aware that I can run:

```
pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --onefile --name=owl --additional-hooks-dir=. --hidden-import=win32timezone --hidden-import=pyodbc service.py
```

And it produces the correct spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['service.py'], pathex=['D:\\Python\\HooksTest'], binaries=[], datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone', 'pyodbc'], hookspath=['.'], runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[], win_no_prefer_redirects=False, win_private_assemblies=True,
             cipher=block_cipher, noarchive=False)
```

But it does not work as expected when I use a hook file. I need to get hooks working for our CI builds.